# Unit testing of a Sitecore item using fakeDb

Tags: c#, unit-testing, sitecore

I am currently trying to create a unit test for an override I made, but unit testing seems a bit more difficult than I expected.

```
public class Extension
{
    public fallback(HttpContext context)
    {
       return new HttpContext();
    }  

    public IEnumerable<SiteDefinition> RunOn => new[]
    {
       "Some", "Dome", "Gone"
    };

    public bool AllowedOnSite(string site)
    {
        bool allowed = RunOn.Any(sd => sd.Name == site);
        return allowed;
    }

    protected bool Process(HttpContext context)
    {
        var site = Context.Site.Name;
        if (Context.Domain.Name == "sitecore" || !AllowedOnSite(site))
        {
            return fallback(context);
        } 
     ....

    }
```

I seem to have a problem with `AllowedOnSite`, I can unit test it by itself, but not as part of `Process`, which is needed to unit test the rest of the code.

How do I include `AllowedOnSite` as always `true`, as part of the unit test for `Process`?

Unit test:

```
    [Theory]
    [CustomAutoData("Gonw")]
    public void AllowedOnSite_IncorrectSite_ReturnFalse(string site)
    {
        //arrange
        var processor = new MediaRequestExtensions();

        //act
        processor.AllowedOnSite(site);

        //assert
        Assert.False(processor.AllowedOnSite(site));
    }
```

This works as expected, but I don't know how to make this condition `true`, when I run the `Process` method.

```
[Theory]
[CustomAutoData("http://gonw.com","Gonw")]
public void Process_RequestURLIsIncorrect_Return(string url, string name)
{
    // Arrange
    var fakeSite = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Sites.FakeSiteContext(new Sitecore.Collections.StringDictionary
    {
        { "name", "Some" },
        { "b", "Dome" },
        { "c", "Gone" }
    });
    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest(string.Empty, url, string.Empty);
    HttpResponse httpResponse = new HttpResponse(new StringWriter());
    HttpContext httpContext = new HttpContext(httpRequest, httpResponse);

    var processor = new MediaRequestExtensionsMock
    {
        GetHttpContextFunc = () => httpContext
    };
    using (new Db())
    {
        using (new Sitecore.Sites.SiteContextSwitcher(fakeSite))
        {
            Sitecore.Context.Site.Name = name;
            // Act
            processor.Process(httpContext);

            // Assert
            Assert.Equal(string.Empty, httpContext.Response.Output.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I trigger the right `if` statement in this test, but if I want to trigger the next one, I shouldn't trigger the first one, which I can't seem to do.

Could you please advise me?

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: @Nkosi How do i include `AllowedOnSite` as always true, as part of the unittest for `Process`?

Comment: Show the test to which you are referring

Comment: You need to provide an actual [mcve] that can be used to reproduce the problem. The question in its current state does not allow that. We cant assess the cause if the shown classes are made up. What is `Extension : Original`? You have `RunOn =>` yet call `RunOnSites`

Comment: @Nkosi Should be MCV

Comment: Any suggestions @Nkosi